# How to declare a static array in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, static, javascript-objects

I am trying to create a static array named "categories" whom I wish it will be initialized ONCE in my Node.js application. I mean, when I close the app and run it again - I want it to KEEP the state of the "categories" array.
What happens is that the array is initialized for each time I run this app. Though I want it to be declared only once in this app's lifetime.

```
router.post("/add_category", (req, res, next) => {
   var category = req.body.category;
   categories.push(category);
   res.render("index", { categories });
});
```

Comment: Where is the array `categories` declaration?

Comment: For now, I declared it in the index router as a global variable.

Comment: "I mean, when I close the app and run it again - I want it to KEEP the state of the "categories" array." it seems to me the definition of a database.

Comment: You could try fs.writeFile or readFile functions to persists JSON.stringified objects like arrays. But a database would be better.

Comment: Yeah I thought about that solution but it is wasteful for only few entries... Isn't it possible storing that in a static array?

Answer (score 2):

You should need a database for that kind of data persistence. But at times, a full-blown database (MongoDB, SQL) could be considered overkill since you only need to save a simple array. 
So, consider using the "node-persist" package, here's a possible solution:

```
const storage = require('node-persist');
storage.initSync();
storage.setItem('categories', [ . . . ] );
console.log(storage.getItem('categories'));
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution is to just write the array to a file as JSON and then load that back in when your server starts.

```
let categories = require('./categories.json');

router.post("/add_category", (req, res, next) => {
   var category = req.body.category;
   categories.push(category);
   fs.writeFile(`./categories.json`, JSON.stringify(categories), () => {
       res.render("index", { categories });
   });
});
```

Node.js, by itself, does not have any automatically persisted variables that get saved to disk by themselves and are automatically available the next time you run the program.  You have to code that yourself.

Comment: @JonathanMorag - Note, you should create a default `./categories.json` file before you run the program or modify the code to handle the file not existing at first.

Answer (score 0):

That is was databases are for. Consider Using some SQL or noSQL database that will store values even if server is reseted.